# Set cell text label to text passed through delegate function

Tags: ios, swift

I have some text that is being passed to my view controller, and I am trying to set the cell label text to this.

```
class oneViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITextFieldDelegate, TypingDelegate {
    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

    var someText:String = ""

    ...

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        print("TextA: \(someText)")

        let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")
        cell.textLabel.text = someText

        return cell
    }

    ...

    func data(passedData:String) {
        someText = passedData
        print("TextB: \(someText)")
    }

    ...

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "showSecondVC" {
            let sendingVC:OtherViewController = segue.destination as! OtherViewController
            sendingVC.myDelegate = self
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this code I get:

```
TextB: "pizza"
TextA: ""
```

It seems like the passed value of "pizza" is overwritten to "" every time the view is loaded. How do you take the passed data from the delegate function and set the cell text label to that value?

**Edit**

Here is the code of the other (sending VC):

```
protocol TypingDelegate {
    func data(passedData:String)
}

class TypingViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UISearchResultsUpdating, UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchControllerDelegate {

    var myDelegate:TypingDelegate? = nil

    ...

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false)
        if myDelegate != nil {
            let passedData = "pizza"
            myDelegate?.typingData(passedName: passedName)
            searchController.isActive = false
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "showOtherVC", sender: self)
        }
    }

    ...

}
```

Thanks

Comment: Add the code where you are calling the `data(passedData:)` function

Comment: I added the other code..

Comment: Is the "showOtherVC" segue an unwind segue?  You are probably pushing/presenting another copy of `oneViewController` on top of your `TypingViewController` instead of popping/dismissing your `TypingViewController` to reveal your current `oneViewController`.

Comment: Ahhhh Thank you, that was it. I was pushing another copy. Changing the performSegue to dismiss() fixed it

Answer (score 0):

The unexpected behavior may be caused by your delegate function being called AFTER the table view loads.

Simply do this to reload the tableView after the delegate function is called

```
  func data(passedData:String) {
    someText = passedData
    print("TextB: \(someText)")
    tableView.reloadData()
  }
```

Note that this will set the text label for every cell to `someText`. Use a collection type (array, dictionary) to store ordered values that you can read in accordance with the indexPath's row property ( `indexPath.row`)

Comment: I gave this a try, and I still have the same result. Any other ideas?